# Bone constrained to external object, how do I edit or remove this constraint?

Tags: animation, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

So I created a character model a little while ago, did some animations that involved that character being in handcuffs, and do so this, I somehow constrained the IK controller of the hands to the hand cuffs, but I don't remember how I did it. So, when the handcuffs move, the hands follow their location (staying in the cuffs).

Now, I want to edit / remove this constraint (to use the same character in a different scene) and I have NO IDEA how to find or do it. It's not in the constraints tab, I can't find the anywhere to edit or adjust this constraint. I know it's kind of dumb of me, but can anyone help?

(It's blender 3.3, BTW)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, after clicking around I figured it out, it was "copy location constraint" under "bone constraints". Very dumb of me to miss that in retrospect. I'll leave this here for anyone who wants to know how to constrain bones or edit bone constraints, it's under the "bone constraints" tab.